# How to bind a click event on “v-html” in Vue

Tags: events, click, vue.js

I have a simple example in jsfiddle, as described in the example, I want to insert the element via v-html and then bind the event in the insert element. In addition to adding id operation dom this way, is there a better way?

https://jsfiddle.net/limingyang/bnLmx1en/1/

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div v-html="link"></div>
</div>

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        link: '<a href="javascript:void(0)">click me</a>'
    }
})
```

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML says that bindings are ignored.
The thing you can do it something like this `<div @click="yourMethod" v-html="link"></div>`

Comment: I just want to bind the event to `a`.

Comment: @BelminBedak I tried like this, but this is not working, it will not click the div.

Answer (score 26):

You can add a [ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) on your `div`, and operate with its children elements like you do in regular JavaScript. For example, you can set an event listener for a link inside `mounted` hook:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    link: '<a href="#">click me</a>'
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$refs['mydiv'].firstChild.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log('clicked: ', event.target);
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div v-html="link" ref="mydiv"></div> <!-- notice 'ref' -->
</div>
```

Comment: I've been banging my head to get this to work.  This works perfectly for what I needed.

Comment: This does not seem to work when the v-html is dynamically updated.

Comment: @svenema put it in a method function and run the function again when things change

Comment: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" I'm getting that error with your code

Answer (score 1):

For people having problem with @tony19 solution:

If your v-html is dynamically updated and you want to do something on the element you have to use

```
Vue.nextTick(() => {});
```

Because you have to wait for the DOM to create the element before accessing its child nodes.