# Add click event to Vue prop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a vue component that has numerous props and have come across a slight issue. This CTA component button can have a footnote as a prop which can also contain a link, as this one does. Is it possible to add a click event (google analytics tracker) to this link even though it is a string?

```
        <CTA
          title="Sign up for Savings"
          sub-title="Learn about the different ways<br> to save.<sup>&dagger;</sup>"
          :has-button="true"
          button-text="Sign up"
          button-href="/savings-and-support/savings"
          :has-footnote="true"
          footnote="<sup>&dagger;</sup>Restrictions apply. See <a @click='WHERE I WANT GA CLICK EVENT' href='/savings-and-support/savings#terms' style='text-decoration:underline'>eligibility requirements</a> for more information."
          @click="$ga.event('navigation', 'click', 'barker')">
        </CTA>
```

component:

```
<template>
  <div class="cta-column" :class="{ 'cta-column--one-item': oneColumn }">
    <div class="icon">
      <slot name="icon"></slot>
    </div>

    <div class="cta callout-row__cta-title">
      <h2 v-html="title"></h2>
    </div>

    <div class="cta-sub-title">
      <p v-html="subTitle"></p>
    </div>

    <template v-if="hasButton">
      <router-link v-if="useRouterLink" :to="buttonHref" class="cta__button button" v-html="buttonText"> </router-link>

      <a v-else :href="buttonHref" class="cta__button button" v-html="buttonText"> </a>
    </template>

    <div class="cta-footnote" v-if="hasFootnote">
      <p class="footnote" v-html="footnote"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'CTA',
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    subTitle: {
      type: String,
      required: false
    },
    hasButton: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false
    },
    buttonText: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    footnote: {
      type: String,
      required: false
    },
    hasFootnote: false,
    oneColumn: false,
    buttonHref: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    useAnchor: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bind a click event on “v-html” in Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44483117/how-to-bind-a-click-event-on-v-html-in-vue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could forward the `click` event from `CTA` by binding a `click`-handler to the footer's `p` that re-emits the event (with [`$emit()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit)):

```html
<p class="footnote" @click="$emit('click', $event)" v-html="footnote"></p>
```

That would allow you to bind `click`-handlers on select `CTA` that require analytics (i.e., `<CTA @click="$ga(...)">`).

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/click-event-forwarding-in-vue-forked-bs3sy?file=/src/components/CTA.vue:138-219)

Comment: Now is it ok to pass the GA event directly to the component like so:

@click="$ga.event('navigation', 'click', 'barker)"

or is a method needed for the event?

Comment: It's fine to do that. The `v-bind` directive internally wraps the handler value (`$ga.event(...)`) with a function that gets executed upon the event (not immediately).